# add scss (bootstrap) compilation with output css file in react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-sass

I have a react/express project
I want to be able to customize the Bootstrap 4 and output a CSS file which will contain the customized boostrap.css.

I have npm installed the loaders bootstrap needs ( postcss-loader,sass-loader,style-loader etc), although in web I saw an example with ExtractTextPlugin in order to get output file

when I run the webpack config I get an error 
" throw new Error("'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename");"

Any tutorial/help how to accomplish compiling customized bootstrap in seperate output file?

```
webpack config

const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  //root file for the client/browser app
  entry: './src/client/client.js',

  //output file and its location
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public'),
  },

  //run babel for every filename
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets:
          [
            'react',
            'stage-0',
            [
              'env',
              {
                targets:
                {
                  browsers:
                  ['last 2 versions']
                }
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
module.exports = {
  //  root file for the client/browser app
  entry: './src/client/styles/main.scss',

  //  output file and its location
  output: {
    filename: 'styles2.css',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css', {
      allChunks: true,
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra `module.exports`. I do not see the need to have two of these as you can simply achieve the same thing inside a single `module.exports`.

You can achieve this like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  //root file for the client/browser app
  entry: [
    './src/client/client.js',
    './src/client/styles/main.scss'
  ],

  //output file and its location
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'public'),
  },

  //run babel for every filename
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets:[
           'react',
           'stage-0',
           [
             'env',
              {
                targets:
               {
                browsers:
                ['last 2 versions']
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css', {
      allChunks: true,
    })
   ]
 },};
```

Comment: I did what you suggest earlier, but didn't product any style.css in my public folder

Comment: Did it still produce the error you mentioned in the post? Also, I forgot to write sass-loader instead of sass

Comment: No, it didn't thats why i thought i didn't anything and tried to create 2 modules.exports

Comment: Have you tried the update answer? That is, putting sass-loader and css-loader instead of sass and css

Comment: yes ('css-loader!sass-loader') , maybe there is problem because bootstrap on their site declare it needs postcss-loader ?